# File is not defined node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Do you have an idea how will I do theline of code below in node JS?

```
const file = new File([Data], `${filename}.card`, { type: 'application/octet-stream', lastModified: Date.now() });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `writeFileSync()` method from the [file system API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to write to a file in Nodejs:

```
/* 
Example of data being transformed into a buffer suitable for writing 
to file:

const Data = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]; 
const buffer = Buffer.from(Data);
*/

fs.writeFileSync(`${filename}.card`, buffer)
```

Comment: How about the type?

Comment: the type is implicit based on the contents of Data - see updated answer showing conventional usage of `writeFileSync` with a buffer created from an array of Data

Comment: Thanks @Dacre, will try it.